# Installing haxe

Tags: classpath, flashdevelop, haxe

I have a problem with programming in Haxe. Whenever I try to run a code, I get an error:

> Please don't add haxe/std to your classpath, instead set HAXE_STD_PATH env var.

I tried to find a solution - according to multiple sites, I'm supposed to change the environment variable `HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH` to `HAXE_STD_PATH` and set the value to actual path to the std file in my `haxe` folder. In my case, there was no such variable among my env vars, so I made `HAXE_STD_PATH` as a new one - and I still get the same error.

I'm using FlashDevelop and when I try to search for any class that would reference `std`, I can see in Type Explorer that there is a classpath that leads straight to `haxe/std`, which should not happen IMO. I looked at classpaths in Properties and the path to std was not listed, so I could not change it.
So problem could be in the classpath or in FlashDevelop settings.

Did anyone have the same problem? 
Oh, and BTW I'm using Windows - and yes, restarting did not help.

Comment: AFAIK and according to [this](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxelib/pull/94), HAXEPATH, HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH are needed. Haven't used FlashDevelop so far, so take this with a grain of salt. I may be wrong ref your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. I removed all: FD including program settings and HaxeToolkit (the whole map).
2. Then I reinstalled FD, Haxe (using the apps window from FD), Lime and openFL (from command window).

**Now I don't get this error anymore.**